# convert pymongo cursor to json

Tags: pymongo

- I know this is a fairly common problem. I'm writing a small Flask app and I'm trying to feed some queries back to the view.
  I've connected to my local MongoDB setup, and made a successful query - but I can't generate a json object with it.

The most common solution I've seen is to import json_util from pymongo i.e.

```
import json
from pymongo import json_util

results = connection.get_collection('papayas_papaya')
results = results.find({
    'identifier': '1',
})
serialized_results = [json.dumps(result, default=json_util.default, separators=(',', ':')) for result in results]
```

I've installed pymongo into my Flask virtualenv using pip i.e :

```
pip install pymongo
```

When running the above code I keep getting the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name json_util
```

I can see this line in the pymongo-2.3-py2.6.egg-info/installed-files.txt
    ../bson/json_util.py

Anyone got any tips that can help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE**:
Having noodled about with this a little further - I've managed to get this working thus:

```
import pymongo
from bson.json_util import dumps

connection = pymongo.Connection("localhost", 27017)
db = connection.mydocs

def get():
    cursor = db.foo.find({"name" : "bar"})
    return dumps(cursor)
```

One of the problems I had was trying to pip install bson independently - pymongo brings bson with it and importing bson separately caused problems.

Thanks @Cagex for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: Never "pip install bson", that's someone else's obsolete module. Only "pip install pymongo" to get the official pymongo, bson, and gridfs modules.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It looks like you want to import from bson not pymongo.  I believe json_util was moved to that module recently.
https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/bson/json_util.html

Comment: url not work 202111005

Answer (score 6):

I've seen quite a few posts on this issue but they didn't resolve the issue for me. What worked for me was using **dumps()**, then **loads()**:

```py
import pymongo
from bson.json_util import dumps
from bson.json_util import loads
    
connection = pymongo.Connection("localhost", 27017)
db = connection.mydocs
    
def get():
    cursor = db.foo.find({"name" : "bar"})
    return loads(dumps(cursor))
```

Comment: This prints only the headings and not the values

Answer (score 2):

you can use list() to convert pymongo cursor to json object.

```
import pymongo
from bson.json_util import dumps
from bson.json_util import loads

connection = pymongo.Connection("localhost", 27017)
db = connection.mydocs

def get():
   cursor = list(db.foo.find({"name" : "bar"}))
   return loads(dumps(cursor))
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need define your own `JSONEncoder`:

```
import json
from datetime import datetime
from typing import Any

from bson import ObjectId


class MongoJSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o: Any) -> Any:
        if isinstance(o, ObjectId):
            return str(o)
        if isinstance(o, datetime):
            return str(o)
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, o)
```

And then use it to encode the Mongo cursor:

```
data_json = MongoJSONEncoder().encode(list(cursor))
```

that you can then load as a Python object with `json.loads()`:

```
data_obj = json.loads(data_json)
```