# Pymongo/bson: Convert python.cursor.Cursor object to serializable/JSON object

Tags: python, json, mongodb, pymongo, webapp2

New to MongoDb and Python (`webapp2`). So, I was fetching some data from a **mongodb** database. But I was unable to use `json.dumps` on the returned data. Here's my code:

```
exchangedata = db.Stock_Master.find({"Country": "PHILIPPINES"}, {"_id" : 0})        
self.response.write(json.dumps(exchangedata))
```

This throws an error:

```
TypeError: pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x7fcd51230290 is not JSON serializable
```

The type of `exchangedata` is `pymongo.cursor.Cursor`. How can I convert it into a json object?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13241878/convert-pymongo-cursor-to-json.

Comment: Convert the cursor to a list of objects: `self.response.write(json.dumps(list(exchangedata)))`

Comment: Mongo returns a `cursor` object instead of an actual `list` of data. You will need to convert that to a `list` first as Kyle mentioned.

Comment: Not working with the list wrapper. It sends across an empty data object.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use dumps from [bson.json_util](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/bson/json_util.html):

```
>>> c = pymongo.MongoClient()
>>> c.test.test.count()
5
>>> from bson.json_util import dumps
>>> dumps(c.test.test.find())
'[{"_id": {"$oid": "555cb3a7fa5bd85b81d5a624"}}, {"_id": {"$oid": "555cb3a7fa5bd85b81d5a625"}}, {"_id": {"$oid": "555cb3a7fa5bd85b81d5a626"}}, {"_id": {"$oid": "555cb3a7fa5bd85b81d5a627"}}, {"_id": {"$oid": "555cb3a7fa5bd85b81d5a628"}}]'
```

Comment: this solution is good only for very small dataset as it dumps all of the objects fetched by the cursor to a single string. With bigger data it doesn't help and you can as well iterate over all of the results and just save them.

Comment: bson package is really bad for large data. Use the bsonjs package instead. In most cases it should suffice for you to convert the ObjectId() alone.

Comment: dumps(c.test.test.find(), indent=4) is better.

Answer (score 2):

> Simple Solution

```
 // Use dumps from bson.json_util:
from bson.json_util import dumps

@app.route("/")
def home_page():

    booking = dumps(mongo.db.bookings.find())
    print booking
    return  booking
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course you can use the dumps() in bson.json_util package. But, the dumps() will give you quoted results. To get clear json result you can use the following code.

```
clean_json = re.compile('ISODate\(("[^"]+")\)').sub('\\1', 
        dumps(my_db._my_collection.find(query), 
                 json_options=CANONICAL_JSON_OPTIONS))
json_obj = json.loads(clean_json)
```