# Pymongo returning all documents including objectID

Tags: python-2.7, aws-lambda, pymongo

I am making an api to return all documents inside a collection. The code I have right now works fine as long as I don't include the _id (object id) field. If i don't exclude the _id it throws an error

> TypeError: ObjectId('') is not JSON serializable

This is my Current Code snippet:

```
@application.route('/get_all_societies', methods=['GET'])
def get_all_societies():
    result = list(db['Societies'].find({}, {"_id": 0}))
    return jsonify(success=True, data=result)
```

I want to know the best way to include ObjectId in the result without it throwing an error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21411497/flask-jsonify-a-list-of-objects

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pymongo/bson: Convert python.cursor.Cursor object to serializable/JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30333299/pymongo-bson-convert-python-cursor-cursor-object-to-serializable-json-object)